# Typealias is not imported with my framework

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to write a convenience framework, where I have some functions and some typealiases.

I added my framework to the project, and the functions are imported and work fine. The problem however is that I'm trying to use the typealias that I declared in my framework, and XCode is giving me this compiler error "Use of undeclared type 'Json"

I declared everything public, including the typealiases

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(DBCore.randomInt())
    print(DBCore.randomInt(upTo: 10))
    print(DBCore.randomString())
    var x : Json? // compiler error here "Use of undeclared type 'Json'"

}
```

The framework code:

```
import Foundation

public class DBCore{

    public static func randomString() ->String{
        return UUID().uuidString
    }

    public static func randomInt() -> Int{
        return Int(arc4random())
    }

    public static func randomInt(upTo upperBound : Int) -> Int{
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upperBound)))
    }
}

public typealias Json = [String : Any]
public typealias JsonArray = [Json]
```

Comment: Try restarting the `Xcdoe`.

Comment: I did that prior to posting the question, it didn’t help

Comment: Did you imported the framework

Comment: yes,of course I imported the framework, Im using functions from that framework.

Comment: Same problem here! Any solutions?

Comment: @NickPodratz not as of right now

Comment: Hmmm. This is super annoying. Is it maybe considered a preprocessor statement that is resolved before packing the library? Do I need to wrap it into some structure?

Comment: Did you try to import the typealias explicitly?

Comment: Try to select legacy build system

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue with my framework and external project. The regular fixes (clean, derived data, and restart xcode) didn't work for me either.

I found that I had another type already using my desired typealias in my external project. Since you've named your variable the common name of `Json`, it's probably getting overwritten by the system `JSON` var or perhaps another var in your external project.

If you feel you have to keep the name, you can reference it specifically by calling the typealias from the framework explicitly.

Framework:

```
public typealias MyTypeAlias = ((Bool) -> Void)
public protocol MyDelegate {
    func myFunc(with fancyType: MyTypeAlias)
}
```

External Project:

```
@import MyFramework

public class MyLocalDelegate: MyDelegate {
    func myFunc(with fancyType: MyFramework.MyTypeAlias) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Maybe selecting legacy build system in workspace settings will avoid `clean, derived data, and restart xcode`